# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS restarting problem

Tags: boot

Two days ago I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS via USB flash drive. The installation was fresh and there were no problems during it.

At the end of the installation, I was prompted to restart the computer. I hit the restart button, then the Ubuntu logo showed up and after that the screen went black. After waiting 10 to 15 minutes, I pressed my power button twice. Then my computer started up again.

I still have the same problem when I reboot my PC. The Ubuntu logo shows for a single time, then the screen goes black. When I press the power button twice, then my PC starts up.

So, where is the problem?